# Not able to connect to another user's office 365 Mailbox using EWS API

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

There is a **user A** which has full access permission on **user B's mailbox**, but from EWS api the user A is not being able to connect to B's mailbox.
If I signed in as user **A from OWA** and open B's mailbox , I can open it.
There are other u**sers C,D....** and A has full access permission on their mailboxes as well and I can successfully connect to their mailboxes.

Here is the code:

```
    var folderView = new FolderView(20, 0)
    {
        PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly)
        {
            FolderSchema.DisplayName,
            FolderSchema.ChildFolderCount
        },
        Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow
    };

    var mailbox = new Mailbox(B);
    var rootFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, mailbox);

    FindFoldersResults findFolderResults;
    findFolderResults = exchangeService.FindFolders(rootFolderId, folderView);
    var count = findFolderResults.TotalCount; // This count is always 0 for user B
```

Comment: Is there an error? Have you done tracing to see the requests and responses?

Comment: Should not there be an exception if an error were to occur?